# How to use jooq to express mysql REGEXP?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

I have query like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM uni_customer 
WHERE mobile REGEXP '^(1[3,4,5,8]){1}\\d{9}$'
```

But there is no such function like `REGEXP(String)` in field,
and mysql don't support syntax like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM uni_customer 
WHERE  regexp(mobile,'^(1[3,4,5,8]){1}\\d{9}$')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official [support for the `REGEXP` operator](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/620) will be available soon in the upcoming jOOQ 2.5.0. In the mean time, you can extend jOOQ yourself, as such:

```
Condition regexp = Factory.condition("{0} REGEXP {1}", 
                                     UNI_CUSTOMER.MOBILE,
                                     val("^(1[3,4,5,8]){1}\\d{9}$"));
```

Or in a query:

```
create.select()
      .from(UNI_CUSTOMER)
      .where(condition("{0} REGEXP {1}", 
                       UNI_CUSTOMER.MOBILE, val("^(1[3,4,5,8]){1}\\d{9}$")));
```